# TinyMCE render listbox items as html

Tags: listbox, tinymce

I created a TinyMCE plugin and need the listbox items to display html. This is my plugin:

```
editor.addButton('icons', {
  title: 'Foo',
  text: 'Foo',
  type: 'button',
  onclick: function() {
    editor.windowManager.open({
      title: 'Foo',
      width: 300,
      height: 200,
      body: [{
        type: 'listbox',
        label: 'Foo',
        name: 'foo',
        values: [{
          title: '<em>Foo</em>', // <-- Mark save. Render as html.
          value: 1
        }],
      }],
    });
  }
});
```

See also the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/allcaps/vqctac3d/

But the output looks like:

[image]

Expected:

[image]

How can I mark the list option title save so the contents is rendered as html?

Comment: I think my vocabulary is to limited to think of appropriate search phrases... So any pointers are welcome.

Comment: Why don't you use css to style the list title and list items?

Comment: How do I select those list items? I can't set a class or id. Selecting by index will not work with dynamic content.

Comment: @Thariama: Thanks for the hint. If I can select list items I can replace them. I know the ordering. So that is a workaround.

Comment: @allric: Yes, selection by index doesn't work with dynamic content. In case you know the ordering this is indeed a workaround. The problem with the creation of list items is that you cannot insert html on tinymce creation no matter what. Tinymce is not able to treat them otherwise (as html) for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is your updated snippet:**

https://jsfiddle.net/mzvarik/1cwr07z6/55/

---

I was looking for same thing but listbox and it can be done like this:

(see fiddle for more)

```js
editor.addButton('myshortcuts', {
 type: 'listbox',
 text: 'Vložit proměnnou',
 values: self.shortcuts_data,
 onselect: function() {
               // do something
  this.value(null); //reset selected value
 },
onShow: function (event) {
 var panel = $(event.control.getEl()),
  button = event.control.parent().getEl();
 
 var i=0;
 panel.find('.mce-text').each(function(){
  var item = $(this);
  if (!item.next('.mce-menu-shortcut').length) {
                                // THIS WILL ADD HTML TO EXISTING MENU ITEM
   item.after('<div class="mce-menu-shortcut">('+self.shortcuts_data[i].value+')</div>');
  }
  i++;
 });
 
 setTimeout(function(){
  panel.css('width', 360);
  panel.children().first().css('width', 360);
 }, 5);
 
}

});
```

**Here is screenshot:**

[image: Here is screenshot:]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This had my interest long time ago and can't verify if this works (and if this was possible in a Tiny from 3 years ago). But I'll mark your answer accepted anyway.

Comment: @allcaps Thanks, I updated the answer and added your snippet ;)

Comment: yupp, with tinymce 4 this is possible

Answer (score 2):

Since noone else answered this question i will put the proposed solution/workaround from the comment into an answer.

Actually, it is not possible to insert html code using the tinymce way of listbox creation. But it is possible to style listboxes using css.

Due to the fact that listboxes and other tinymce UI elements get rendered dynamically it might be difficult to adress the correct html dom elements.

A workaround to this can be to exchange the listbox html after the listbox has been created. This is possible in case the ordering is known (and that is almost true).