# show hover tooltip on custom formatted element in tinymce editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

I want to show my `provision` value in a tooltip on hover selected element in tinymce editor.

I have something like this:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    menubar: false,
    toolbar: [
        'undo redo | styleselect | removeformat'
    ],
    statusbar: false,
    height: 300,
    style_formats:[
         {
           title: "Provisions",
           items: [
                 {title: 'Provision1', inline: 'span', 'classes': 'provision provision-1'},
                 {title: 'Provision2', inline: 'span', 'classes': 'provision provision-2'},
           ]
        },
    ],
    content_style: ".provision {background: #c4dce8}",
});
```

I want to see the provision title in the tooltip when I hover some formated  line in my text.

When I select line of text in my paragraph and format it as a provision, classes and styles are appending. It works but how can I include a tooltips to these selected elements?

Many thanks for help.

Comment: This might be alternative, but doesn't use tooltip: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52558035/1347572